# Serenity screenplay rest extract value from response

Tags: java, lambda, return, serenity-bdd

I'm trying to extract class Header from response but can't find solution to that can please anyone guide me on this ?

```
Actor actor = Actor.named("ADMIN").whoCan(CallAnApi.at(baseUrl));
        actor.attemptsTo(Get.resource("headers/" + rsplId).with(request -> request.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
                .cookies(cookies)));
        actor.should(seeThatResponse(response -> response.assertThat().statusCode(200)
                .extract().response().as(Header.class) 
        ));
```

actor.should is void and when I tried to find anything inside seeThatResponse static method returning ReponseConsequence and see the message only thing I found inside was message that it was succesfull.

My method is returning Header but I don't know how to return this extracted Header inside response -> response.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution with this approach maybe it'll help someone in the future.

```
actor.should(seeThatResponse(response -> response.assertThat().statusCode(200)));
        return SerenityRest.lastResponse().as(Header.class);
```